# unresolved overloaded function error when binding to std::operator==

Tags: c++

I am trying to bind to `bool std::operator==(const std::string&, const std::string&)`, but I'm getting an error that I hope somebody can help me with.

```
std::string v1 = "foo";
std::string v2 = "foo";

bool r = 
    std::bind(
        static_cast<bool(*)(const std::string&, const std::string&)>(&std::operator== ),
        std::placeholders::_1,
        std::cref(v1))(v2);


error: invalid static_cast from type '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to type 'bool (*)(const string&, const string&) {aka bool (*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, const std::basic_string<char>&)}'
             &std::operator== ), 
                              ^
```

example: [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/QYPvpy)

Comment: Isn't your inner voice telling you that probably you shouldn't be using this stuff? `std::bind` was meant to be a joke, not something to be used for real...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disambiguating `std::operator==` solves your problem, but it isn't the cleanest looking code:

```
bool r = 
        std::bind(
            static_cast<bool(*)(const std::string&, const std::string&)>(operator==<char, std::string::traits_type, std::string::allocator_type>),
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::cref(v1))(v2);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Pradhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28267303/2069064) gives you the correct syntax for using bind in this spot. Which seems like a *great* reason to not use `bind` in this spot and to prefer a lambda:

```
bool r = [&v1](const std::string& rhs){
    return rhs == v1;
}(v2);
```